# Choosing WordPress REST API

Tags: ios, rest, wordpress

I'm developing an iOS client for a WordPress blog. Currently I am in the process of figuring out which REST API to interface with. It seems that these are the two main options:

- https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/
- http://v2.wp-api.org/

Has anyone who's built a WordPress client before have any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be confused, [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/about/) and [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/about/) are [completely different organizations](https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/).

wordpress.com offers its own version of WordPress with custom features and API.

So if you host your site on wordpress.com, use [their API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/). If your site is a self-hosted site, use [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org) plugin.

Comment: perfect, this is exactly the answer I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API has been added to the core in Wordpress 4.7, so if you update WP to the latest version, you don't need to install the WP REST API plugin. 
The documentation can be found here now: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/